# ¿Cómo subir un archivo a s3 con html y nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, aws

Actualmente puedo subir los archivos, desde nodejs, pero lo quenecesto es que se puedean cargar desde una ventana y elegir el archivo que se desea enviar, necesito obtener el nombre para poder sustituirlo en la función fs, pero no se si también necesite al url del mismo. Estoy usando aws-sdk, y la función fs para poder subir el archivo. Mi código está de la siguiente manjera

```
<div style="margin-left: 410px;" class="container p-4">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
            <h1>Cargue su archivo</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="file" accept=".pdf, .jpg" multiple="multiple" id="archivo" onchange="getname()"/>        
                <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-2x bottom pulsating"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x top medium"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-stack-1x top"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="desc">Pulse aquí para añadir archivos</span>
            </div>
            <label id="fichero" for="archivo" class="my-btn btn-danger">Archivo 1</label><br>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="cars">Seleccione el tipo de archivo</label>

                <select id="cars">
                <option value="contrato">Contrato</option>
                <option value="declaracion">Declaracion Juarada</option>
                <option value="autentica">Autentica de documento</option>
                <option value="escriturapu">Escritura Pública</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            </div>
            <h1>

            </h1>
            <a class="btn btn-danger white" onclick="getname()()">
                Enviar
            </a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

y el js

```
function getname(){
    var resultado = document.getElementById('archivo').files[0].name;
    console.log(resultado);
    function enviar(){

        fs.readFile(resultado,(err,data)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
            var paramputobj= {
                Bucket: 'archivos-contrato',
                Key: 'contratos/'+resultado,
                Body: data
            }
            s3.putObject(paramputobj, (err, data)=>{
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(data);
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El navegador web no tiene acceso al sistema de archivos del usuario, o al menos no ofrece la API `fs` que es especifica de Node.js. No obstante es posible capturar el contenido de un campo de formulario usado para seleccionar un archivo. Puedes ver aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications . Ya que el codigo de la libreria AWS se ejecute sin problemas en el navegador es otro reto pues la configuracion del Bucket en AWS es diferente si la subida del fichero se va a hacer desde el navegador. Para mas detalles ver aqui https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Te recomiendo probar el desarrollo que haces con un contenido de un archivo de muestra copiado en una variable dentro de tu Javascript y probar la parte de la logica que se encarga de enviar ese contenido a AWS S3 y luego resolver el problema de capturar el contenido del formulario. Porque son 2 problemas diferentes.